# "Country" property missing in GMSAutocompleteFilter from Google maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my iOS project I am using Google maps SDK for fetching auto complete address. Hence I want to restrict my results to a specific country According to Google documentation I have to use "country" property of **GMSAutocompleteFilter** class. In Google documentation it has "country" property actual .h file in Google maps SDK it doesn't.

Documentation link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_filter.html#properties

GMSAutocompleteFilter.h  File:

```
//
//  GMSAutocompleteFilter.h
//  Google Maps SDK for iOS
//
//  Copyright 2014 Google Inc.
//
//  Usage of this SDK is subject to the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of
//  Service: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms
//

/**
 * The type filters that may be applied to an autocomplete request to restrict results to different
 * types.
 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter) {
  /**
   * All results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter,
  /**
   * Geeocoding results, as opposed to business results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode,
  /**
   * Geocoding results with a precise address.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterAddress,
  /**
   * Business results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "sublocality"
   * "postal_code",
   * "country",
   * "administrative_area_level_1",
   * "administrative_area_level_2"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "administrative_area_level_3"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity,
};

/**
 * This class represents a set of restrictions that may be applied to autocomplete requests. This
 * allows customization of autocomplete suggestions to only those places that are of interest.
 */
@interface GMSAutocompleteFilter : NSObject

/**
 * The type filter applied to an autocomplete request to restrict results to different types.
 * Default value is kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter.
 */
@property(nonatomic, assign) GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter type;

@end
```

Any Help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally get rid of the issue acknowledged it was due to older version of Google maps iOS SDK. I had been fetching Google SDK without specifying any version number in podfile it gave me like 1.10 version. Hence I updated Google SDK pods with version 1.12.3 then I have the "country" field in **GMSAutocompleteFilter** class.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to update your Google maps SDK. 
https://cocoapods.org/?q=google